# Why this javascript show all the lines togeather and not one by one like in the demo page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://vaakash.github.io/jquery/easy-ticker.js"></script>
<div class="demo3">
        <ul>
            <li>what's causing the layout to break? Attempting to make a horizontal layout website ?</li>
            <li>WordPress Mobify mobile theme, CSS</li>
            <li>Gridview with Table.Rows.Count ==0 to show Footer row that include checkbox with imageurl cast</li>
            <li>JS/jQuery - animated random name picker</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<style>

.demof{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.demof ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.demof li{
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.demof li.odd{
    background: #fafafa;
}
.demof li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.demof img{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
.demof a{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #06f;
}
.demof p {
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.demo3 {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #C20;
    margin: 50px 0;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 0 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -3px #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.demo3:before {
    content: "Latest News";
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    background: #C20;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.demo3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    height: 20px;
}
.demo3 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('.demo3').easyTicker({
                visible: 1,
        interval: 4000,
                direction: 'up'
});
});
</script>
```

The text is scrolling up all ok but in the LatestNews i see all the time 4 lines all the lines of text instead of see each time line by line one line each time like in the demo page:

[Demo Page](http://www.aakashweb.com/demos/jquery-easy-ticker/)

In the LatestNews demo example there is one line each time scrolling up.

What should i change and what cause that so there are 4 lines each time and not one like in the demo page ?

Comment: Another problem i see now the lines of text scrolling up and the beginning of each line is scrolling/touching over the Latest News in the red box.

Comment: Instead of links to your page please include a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)(or similar) as your links to your site, ones they have changed or are dead-links will be of no use to any future user with similar issues. Also, creating a fiddle focusing on an issue sometimes helps in finding the problem before-hand.

Comment: Cool :) Post your fix as an answer and include a jsFiddle (or similar) demonstrating the fix. that would be most usefull to future users with similar issues. When answering your own question you have a cool-down period of a few days than you can accept your own answer.

Comment: I fixed the problem so now its showing one line each time. But still the beginning of the line/s are scrolling over the end of the Latest News box.

Comment: François i will use jsFiddle to show what i have now.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems to work with your code: [http://jsfiddle.net/2WZQP/](http://jsfiddle.net/2WZQP/) The text in it scrolls up every second or so and stays within bounds of the box.

Comment: François i changed now my question i updated the code with what i changed now its showing one line each time thats good but look in my site for second and see that in my site the text is scrolling over the Latest News box. http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html and im using the same code just changed added two lines in the <script> area. For some reason in my site the text is scrolling over the Latest News box.

Comment: In your particular web-site the `.demo 3{padding: 0,0,0,80px}` needs to be increased to something like `.demo 3{padding: 0,0,0,115px}` The reason is the `http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/main_style.css` which is not in the fiddle off course. Open the debugger on your site and highlight the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/main_style.css?1398686941" title="wsite-theme-css">` line and click `delete` and all is fixed. That css has a lot of styles (some with `!important` as well) which are over-writing things. To fix, increase your padding as said earlier by about 40px.

Comment: I wasn't able to add it as an answer earlier. Done that now. glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular web-site that you linked at the time the `padding` as specified in the `.demo3` style is set to `0, 0, 0, 80px`.

That would usually be enough as you can see in this [**isolated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2WZQP/), using your posted code.

Following an inspection of your linked site. The problem seems, that your site also imports another CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/main_style.css?1398686941" title="wsite-theme-css">
```

That file contains all sort of styles, including a few with `!important` and that file seems to over-write or your CSS styles.

IF you open your site, open the debugger and find that `<link...>` line and delete it (from the console only) you will see your HTML will look fine. Mind you, the rest of your site will not.

I don't know how much influence you have over that file but to compensate without changing it change your padding from `80px` to `115px` (or what ever suits) in the `.demo3` style, similar to this:

```
.demo 3{
    ...
    padding: 0, 0, 0, 115px // changed from padding: 0, 0, 0, 80px
    ...
}
```

I tried the above in the console on your site and it seemed to do the trick.